# Variable Height Sidebar Scroll Follow

Tags: jquery, scroll, sidebar, cart

On a website I am working on I am utilizing scroll follow to scroll a cart/items menu with the page. And am using this code
    $(function() {

```
var $sidebar   = $('.sidebar-scroll'),
    $window    = $(window),
    $footer    = $('.footer'), // use your footer ID here
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    foffset    = $footer.offset(),
    threshold  = foffset.top - $sidebar.height(); // may need to tweak
    topPadding = 200;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > threshold) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: threshold
        });
    } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});

});
```

The problem is that because my sidebar is a menu it has a variable height, depending on what a user has selected to add to the cart. How can I modify this code so that my menu DOES NOT go past my footer but can still adjust size accordingly.

Comment: no one can offer any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I've reworked your code by using the **content** as the height reference instead of the footer.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tF8Dj/

```
var $sidebar   = $('aside'),
    $content   = $('#content');

if ($sidebar.length > 0 && $content.length > 0) {
    var $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        timer;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            if ($content.height() > $sidebar.height()) {
                var new_margin = $window.scrollTop() - offset.top;
                if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top && ($sidebar.height()+new_margin) <= $content.height()) {
                    // Following the scroll...
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({ marginTop: new_margin });
                } else if (($sidebar.height()+new_margin) > $content.height()) {
                    // Reached the bottom...
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({ marginTop: $content.height()-$sidebar.height() });
                } else if ($window.scrollTop() <= offset.top) {
                    // Initial position...
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({ marginTop: 0 });
                }
            }
        }, 100); 
    });
}
```

The example assumes that you have a sidebar and content. The timer is there for performance.

Hope it works for you!

EDIT:
I've also found a [Tuts+ tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/spotlight-constrained-stickies-with-jquer/) with a jquery plugin that does the same.